# Conclusions categories with subcategories

Tags: php, yii2

How do I put all the parent categories on one page with links to their child categories, the structure is something like this:

On the same page are all parent categories; When you click on a category, its new categories are displayed on a new page.

CategoryController:

```
public function actionIndex(){
    return $this->render('index', [
        'model' => $this->outTree($id)
    ]);
}

public function getAllArray(){
    $all = Category::find()->all();
    $array = array();
    foreach($all as $v){
        $array[$v->parentId][] = $v;
    }
    return $array;
}

public function outTree($parentId) {
    $array = $this->getAllArray();
    if(isset($array[$parentId])){
        echo '<div>';
        foreach($array[$parentId] as $v){
            echo '<div>'.$v->name.'</div>';
            echo '<div>'.$v->id.'</div>';
            echo '<div>'.$v->parentId.'</div>';
            $this->outTree($v->id);
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
} 

protected function findModel($alias)
{
    if (($model = Category::findOne(['alias' => $alias, 'active' => 1])) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Relationship of parent categories with children:

```
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'parentId']);
}
```

How do I make such a conclusion in the view, now the output goes in the controller? At the moment, all parent categories and their child categories are displayed on the same page. Do I need to register something in UrlManager?

Comment: are you mean you need to display parent category in index page, and if user click on parent you need to go another action and load child, or go to current action with defferant view?!, if any one from that you can determine a parent by any selector/custom href and then go to new action and load child only, or go to current action and load another view render...

Comment: Yes, I just need to link to get child categories, how do I do it, can you please describe here?

Comment: how many levels of category parent you have?, also when you display parent, you display a child in current view, or just a parent and then go to page and display child?

Comment: only 4 levels of nesting, when showing the parent, the child does not need to show, but then go to the page and show the child

Comment: well i would suggest you to use `nested set model` for easily managing these prooblems

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this:

Your Controller:

```
public function actionIndex($parentId = null){
    $models = Category::find()->andWhere(['parent_id' => $parentId])->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'models' => $models
    ]);
}

public function actionGetChilds($parentId){
        $models = Children::find()->andWhere(['parent_id' => $parentId])->all();

        return $this->render('childs', [
            'models' => $models
        ]);
    }
```

You View Page(index):

```
foreach($models as $model): 
    echo Html::a($model->name, Url::to(['index', 'parentId' => $model->parent_id]));
endforeach;
```

Your View Page(child):

```
foreach($models as $model): 
    echo Html::a($model->name, Url::to(['get-childs', 'parentId' => $model->parent_id]));
endforeach;
```

> Note: I think you another relation with name GetChildern in Category
>   Model, you can use it in index action to get all child for category by
>   this `$model->childern`

Comment: thank you, now hatched all parent categories, and to make me to lead on to their child?

Comment: welcome mate, their child exsits in Category table or another table? or its just last level from category?...

Comment: the child is included in the same table of categories, I need to link to display all child categories

Comment: how you can determine record is a child?

Comment: there is a link ' id '= > 'parentId', that is, by clicking on the parent category on the new page displays all child categories whose parentId matches the ID of the parent category

Comment: Thats mean you need to show category and sub category when click on ancour, and also open a new tab has a child for clicked category too? so that you will open 2 page at same time?

Comment: no, I just need to link to show all child categories, that is, initially on one page displays all the parents by clicking on 1 of the parent goes to another page, where all its child categories